# Can Partition images (.img), directly mounted under Linux

Tags: mount

Can partition images like nandc.img uImage are file system, can this mounted directly in Linux? 
mount command?
Data inside image file can be viewed?

Appreciated Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at this related question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82314/how-to-find-the-type-of-img-file-and-mount-it

Answer (score 10):

If it's a raw partition image like dd then mounting is simple, basically

`# mount -t fstype -o loop,ro image.dd /mntpoint`

The `-t fstype` may be optional, it'll be vfat or ext3 or whatever the partition is, sometimes mount can figure it out on it's own so try leaving it out first. And `ro` means read-only.

If it's a multi-partition disk image that's a little trickier, then use kpartx and it creates mappings for each partition which you then mount.

See http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Mounting_Disk_Images for more info, examples, etc.

But, if you're referring to something like a Das U-Boot bootloader embedded system image, that might need tools like dd and the u-boot-tools package's mkimage to extract the filesystem (if there is one) and then mount it. It's rather involved, see this link for info: http://www.isysop.com/unpacking-and-repacking-u-boot-uimage-files/

Answer (score 2):

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=32256 nandc.img nandc
```

Comment: I suppose this snippet shows how one partition can be mounted when nandc.img is a disk image. The `offset=` part can be calculated with `fdisk`: if `fdisk -l nandc.img` says `Units = ... = 512 bytes` and `Device=nandc.img1 / Start=126`, the offset of first partition is then `126*512=32256`.